# disposing WebBrowser control causes opening new page in system browser

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

the issue is the continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698852/why-httpclient-getasync-causes-opening-link-in-browser). A short explanation of problem: I trying to authorize user with OAuth2-like approach on vk.com with WebBrowser in WinForms application, so I need to open application-specific url in webBrowser and vk.com will redirect to authorization page. After authorization vk.com redirects to `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token={accessToken}&expires_in={expiresIn}&user_id={userId}` where I can took token and use it with vk.com API. Everything is good except for the odd page (with url `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token={accessToken}&expires_in={expiresIn}&user_id={userId}%20-%20#access_token={accessToken}&expires_in={expiresIn}&user_id={userId}`) that is opened in the browser at different times following authorization.
I'm a bit reworked sample and now the page does not open in system browser if there is an `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` after disposing WebBrowwser (AuthenticationForm -> authenticationBrowser_DocumentCompleted) control and opens in another case.

**Important:** the bug manifests itself only when had to fill in an authorization form, that is, the Web browser does not contain valid session data. discard session can be going to Settings -> Security of your page -> see the history of activity-> close all sessions

mainForm code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string _token;
    private readonly Uri _redirectUri = new Uri("https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html");
    private readonly Uri _request = new Uri("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get.xml?user_ids=1&fields=online");
    private readonly Uri _authorizationUri =
        new Uri("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3836576&scope=8&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var authenticationForm = new AuthenticationForm();
        authenticationForm.Show();
        _token = await Authenticate(authenticationForm.GetToken);
        authenticationForm.Close();
    }

    private async Task<string> Authenticate(Func<Uri, Uri, Task<string>> aunthenticationResultGetter)
    {
        var token = await aunthenticationResultGetter(_authorizationUri, _redirectUri);
        //...
        return token;
    }

    private async void doRequestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //assume, we using token here
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(_request);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        outputTextBox.AppendText(responseString);
    }
}
```

authenticationForm code:

```
public partial class AuthenticationForm : Form
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<string> _tokenCompletitionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    private Uri _redirectUri;
    private WebBrowser _authenticationBrowser;
    public AuthenticationForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public async Task<string> GetToken(Uri authUri, Uri redirectUri)
    {
        _redirectUri = redirectUri;
        _authenticationBrowser = new WebBrowser
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0),
            MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20),
            Name = "authenticationBrowser",
            ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(641, 353),
            TabIndex = 0
        };
        _authenticationBrowser.DocumentCompleted += authenticationBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
            _authenticationBrowser.Navigate(authUri);
        Controls.Add(_authenticationBrowser);

        var token = await _tokenCompletitionSource.Task;
        return token;
    }
    private void authenticationBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(_redirectUri.IsBaseOf(e.Url) && _redirectUri.AbsolutePath.Equals(e.Url.AbsolutePath))) return;
            _authenticationBrowser.Dispose();
        //GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        //GC.Collect();
        var token = e.Url.ToString().Split('=')[1].Split('&')[0];
        _tokenCompletitionSource.SetResult(token);
    }
}
```

[here is full project code](http://1drv.ms/1gdKG7x)

Comment: Are you sure the same `{accessToken}` token can be used on a different HTTP session? The server has control over this, not the client (unless you manage to replicate the session identity 1:1, which is more than just copying cookies). You need to study the session traffic with Fiddler.

Comment: @Noseratio, somewhere in vk.com api docs told that the token is not bound to http session, it only be bound to ip.

Comment: I don't think it's just the IP address. Think about a typical network NATted behind a single real IP. Anyway, **do not dispose `_authenticationBrowser` inside its own event handler**. Defer the disposal with `form.BeginInvoke`.

Comment: @Noseratio `ALong with access_token, the lifetime of the key will be specified expires_in expressed in seconds. Should the key expire it will be necessary to repeat the steps above, but the user won't have to confirm access rights again. Please note that the given acces_token is linked to the three digits of the IP address of the client, therefore you have to get a new key if the address is changed.` [vk API docs](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=Authorizing_Client_Applications).. Thanks, I`ll try it a little bit later, but I think, it would not solve main problem.

Comment: What happens if you don't `Dispose` the `WebBrowser`, and rather just keep it running hidden in your main form? Does it give you the desired behavior? If not, what *is* the desired behavior?

Comment: @Noseratio if I don`t `Dispose` the `WebBrowser`, but close form in which it is, page still opens with system browser. in WPF, if I set `Visibility` to `Collapsed`, page with that strange and broken url opens in this `WebBrowser` control again. I`ve checked this scenatio in IE11 with Network tools and hadn`t noticed similar behavior: vk.com simply redirects to it`s correct redirect uri with token, expiresIn and userId

Answer (score 0):

I am also ran into a similar problem with the box.com api OAuth integration into my WPF application. But the WPF sample provided by the box.com api works without any issues.

I am unable to reproduce the issue even after I changed the logic and flow of the official sample to match with my WPF application.

Finally I fixed that problem by adding a "about:blank" navigation in the navigating event as shown below, I am sharing the code so that it will help some one.

```
private void browserAuthentication_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Uri.Host.Equals( _callbackUri.Host))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        //This code is required. Otherwise the box api navigation will popup an external browser window.
        browserAuthentication.Navigate("about:blank");

        this._authenticationResponseValues = GetQueryOptions(e.Uri);

    }
}
private IDictionary<string, string> GetQueryStringParamAndValues(Uri resultUri)
{
    string[] queryParams = null;
    var queryValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    int fragmentIndex = resultUri.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("#", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (fragmentIndex > 0 && fragmentIndex < resultUri.AbsoluteUri.Length + 1)
    {
        queryParams = resultUri.AbsoluteUri.Substring(fragmentIndex + 1).Split('&');
    }
    else if (fragmentIndex < 0)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultUri.Query))
        {
            queryParams = resultUri.Query.TrimStart('?').Split('&');
        }
    }

    if (queryParams != null)
    {
        foreach (var param in queryParams)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
            {
                string[] kvp = param.Split('=');
                queryValues.Add(kvp[0], System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(kvp[1]));
            }
        }
    }

    return queryValues;
}
```