# Open link in browser with HttpClient.GetAsync

Tags: c#, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

Is it possible to open a link in browser with `HttpClient.GetAsync`?
I got a report from a user of my app that the app opened a link in the browser which is only used in with HttpClient.GetAsync.
Some one else had the issue too: [why HttpClient.GetAsync causes opening link in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698852/why-httpclient-getasync-causes-opening-link-in-browser)

```
private JObject Get(string url)
{
    JObject getResponse = new JObject();
    getResponse["error"] = (int)Error.None;
    getResponse["message"] = "";
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> res1 = client.GetAsync(url + GetRequestRandomizer());

            HttpResponseMessage res = res1.WaitAndUnwrapException();
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode && res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var responseContent = res.Content;
                getResponse["error"] = (int)Error.None;
                getResponse["message"] = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                getResponse["error"] = (int)Error.RequestError;
                getResponse["message"] = "";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException exception)
    {
        getResponse["error"] = (int)Error.NetworkError;
        getResponse["message"] = "";
    }
    return getResponse;
}
```

Comment: No, no it does not.

Comment: Can you post your relevant part of the code ? May be something else might be causing it to open

Comment: @RiteshKulkarni I added the code.